# Custom Model Validation in ASP.Net core v3.1 MVC ajax form not seems to be working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm working on an ASP.Net core 3.1 MVC project in which I have to create a custom Validator, and I want it to be working for client as well as server side (e.g. Required Attribute).

I developed a simple custom validator like below just for POC -

```
public class ImportantAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {
        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            AttributeUtils.MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
            AttributeUtils.MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-important", FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()));
        }

        public class AttributeUtils
        {
            public static bool MergeAttribute(
                IDictionary<string, string> attributes,
                string key,
                string value)
            {
                if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                attributes.Add(key, value);
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string val = value.ToString();
                if (val.Contains("hello"))
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }
            return new ValidationResult("Value not valid");
        }
    }
```

and used this attribute on a property and created a View using the same model.

Them modified the form tag to become an ajax form like -

```
<form asp-action="Index" role="form" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" value="SGSM" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
 </form>
```

Then I added below java script -

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log('I\'m ready bro');

    $.validator.addMethod("important",
        function (value, element, params) {
            console.log('1', value);
            return value.contains('hello');
        }, "Not OK");

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("important",
        ['important'],
        function (options) {
            console.log('2', options);
            options.rules["important"] = options.important;
            options.messages["important"] = options.message;
        });
});
```

When I run this by providing any value to the text box and submitting the form it don't show any error message on the page, but if I put break point in the Action Method the ModelState shows correct info.

**If I make the form as regular form (i.e. non-ajax form) everything works as expected.**

I have searched a lot but could not find any thing related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code and requirement, I made some some modifications on [custom client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-client-side-validation) code, which works well for me, you can refer it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index" method="post" role="form" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="completed">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(() => {
            console.log('I\'m ready bro');
        });

        completed = () => {
            alert('Request completed!');
        };

        $.validator.addMethod("important",
            function (value, element, params) {
                console.log('1', value);
                return value.includes('hello');
            }, "Not OK");

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("important",
            ['important'],
            function (options) {
                console.log('2', options);

                var element = $(options.form).find('input#Name')[0];

                options.rules["important"] = [element, ''];
                options.messages["important"] = options.message;
            });

    </script>
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: We can do one correction here in this line -> var element = $(options.form).find('input#Name')[0]; replace it with var element = options.element;

Comment: I got a doubt here in `$.validator.addMethod` implementation, is it required to write the validation logic(`value.includes('hello');`) in its callback function also, because it is already written in Custom Validation Attribute?